# Помогите исправить пунктуационные и орфографические ошибки

Tags: пунктуация

А с другой стороны по моему мнению так памятник соответствует поэту. Предполагает характер Бродского. Я может мало знакома с его творчеством,но иногда наткнусь на стих и думаю- ну что за чушь,как много исковерканных авслов,а по сути банальная каша. А потом вижу подпись в конце- Бродский. Аааа....ну опять Бродский, так я и думала! Нахватался от поэтов,которые пережили эпоху,трагедию! А по сути получается "нытье ни о чем" и стиля даже нет. А-ля филосов.

Comment: Какие знаки? Какие ошибки? Такому стилю — такую же пунктуацию, такие же ошибки. Исправлять — только портить.

Comment: Ну какой такой "стиль"... Это та разруха, что не в клозетах, а.

Answer (score 2):

*А с другой стороны, по моему мнению, так памятник соответствует поэту. Предполагает характер Бродского. Я, может, мало знакома с его творчеством, но иногда наткнусь на стих - и думаю: ну что за чушь, как много исковерканных слов, а по сути банальная каша. А потом вижу подпись в конце - Бродский. Ааа... ну опять Бродский, так я и думала! Нахватался от поэтов, которые пережили эпоху, трагедию! А по сути получается нытье ни о чем, и стиля даже нет. А-ля философ.*

> Какие знаки? Какие ошибки? Такому стилю — такую же пунктуацию, такие
>   же ошибки. Исправлять — только портить. – shampar